# Puzzling Poem About Word Puzzles

Tags: word, knowledge, steganography, anagram

Uh oh. I was trying to come up with an interesting puzzle, better than my previous ones, but I have forgotten the correct answer. The solution is a special sequence of 14 seemingly random words. They don't form a meaningful sentence, however, they are arranged in a specific order.  Yet for some weird reason, when I tried to write the sequence, I accidentally wrote a poem instead.

> **Avid Dada Grammar Acclaim**
>   
>   
>   Writing clues to my self, one and two!
>   I repeat another puzzle for that thing and circumscribe the circle's center,
>   Let all puzzlers join and be seated to read the unseen words.
>   Do not ever rush logic or carelessly mix around; kindly wait and discover what we get!
>   Before finding answers, I strum a stringed instrument for hope and find the synonym.
>   I fear the jeering social mockery from enemies until then.
>   Lack of morality turns youths into greedy bootleggers who can neither integrate nor add!
>   Let us steal supplies from pigment artists, and write a ransom letter,
>   Mixing potions in secret dens, brewing toxic alkaloids for fun every now and then.
>   Usually puzzles seem almost like surgical procedures with a nearly unsolvable anagram. 
>   Nor do I know of early keyboards, ciphers, or whatever that is. 
>   Safety first or I sink into small holes, and oh dear, what happens next? 
>   Old honey bees preach about bud arrangements but I ignore every word. 
>   Next, the climate experiences sudden rapid increases of dry clouds raining down.

Could you help me remember the sequence of words?

Comment: 14 lines - probably 14 cryptic clues?

Comment: I don't think you should change the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main clue is

> the last word of each line: "Two center words, get synonym, then add letter, then anagram is next word down".

Thus, the puzzle is

> an Add-A-Gram puzzle!
>  Using the center two words of each line:
>  my self  -> I
>  that thing -> it 
>  be seated    -> sit 
>  mix around   -> stir 
>  string instrument    -> sitar 
>  social mockery   -> satire 
>  greedy bootleggers   -> pirates 
>  pigment artists  -> painters 
>  toxic alkaloids  -> atropines 
>  surgical procedures  -> operations 
>  early keyboards  -> pianofortes 
>  
>  small holes  -> perforations 
>  bud arrangements -> preflorations 
>  rapid increases  -> proliferations

Thus, the sequence is

> I IT SIT STIR SITAR SATIRE PIRATES PAINTERS ATROPINES OPERATIONS PIANOFORTES PERFORATIONS PREFLORATIONS PROLIFERATIONS

Comment: Last one should be proliferations

Comment: just thought of that as well. need to fix the 2nd to last then

Comment: Also Wildbillmunson at the start, who made the first addagrams, and the first syllables of the title - adagrama - i.e. addagrammer.

Comment: @boboquack That was unintentional. For the title, take the first and last letters of each word, and get A_D D_A G_R A_M.